# Is it better to POST using AngularJS $http or jQuery ajax?

Tags: jquery, angularjs, http-post

There are multiple questions here on StackOverflow about how to use php with AngularJS $http post requests as this isn't easy to set up. You have to grab the content, decode the json string, etc.

Given that this is a complicated process, wouldn't it just be easier to create an AngularJS service or factory to send a simpler jQuery $.POST?

Why should or shouldn't I do that?

I know jQuery and AngularJS are not supposed to be mixed up every time you want a shortcut, but this seems cleaner than the AngularJS $http method.

Comment: I don't think there's any reason not to do this if you don't mind the overhead of including jQuery. It's not that complicated with Angular though. You can just do ```$_POST = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);``` for a post request.

Comment: Angular has jQuery light as a default package in it. Yes some times is not enough and you can add the whole jQuery library, to use the extended features. But if you have SPA application with angular it's not a good practice to use $.ajax from jquery. You have to create your own service for that and update your model for example.

Comment: If I'm not wrong you'll have to adapt all $_POST[key] to $_POST->key ? In which case it seems to me that you're more things than a generic jquery post would need...

Comment: Passing true as the second argument to json_decode returns an associative array instead of an object, so you can still use $_POST[$key]